# Place all livestream FB videos from specific FB groups on my website

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, api, live-streaming

Dears,
My goal is to create a webservice which could catch all livestream videos from couple specific FB groups and placed them on my website. I use node.js as a backend for my apps. Is that possible? I would like to avoid crowdlers if possible. Any suggestions? All best

- Googled it with no obvious results
- No code at this point
- Expected results is to get any suggestion which could help me to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, it used to be possible to make an app that would read these posts, filter for live videos, and then embed on your site.

Unfortunately, this is no longer possible.  The APIs that allow apps to retrieve posts from groups no longer work.